# Get selected option using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium WebDriver. I'm testing a drop down list. Here is the code I used to select an item from the drop down.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select")));
dropdown.selectByValue("FEM");
```

This is working fine, but what I need is to get selected item as a text. For an example, under the `value = FEM` , the text displays is female. I need to get the text as Selected value is female.

I've searched some articles and none of this worked. Please help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `element1.selectByVisibleText(value);` if you want to set the option using text instead of value

If you want to get the value use `element1.getAllSelectedOptions().get(0).getText()`

or `element1.getFirstSelectedOption()`

Comment: element1.getAllSelectedOptions().get(0).getText() worked. :)

Comment: @ManuliPiyalka Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Select` has `getFirstSelectedOption()` method. From there you can use `getText()`

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select")));
dropdown.selectByValue("FEM");

WebElement option = dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption();
String text = option.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `dropdown.selectByvalue("FEM")`
use `dropdown.selectByVisibleText("FEM")`